# How to get Font style from UILabel?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

How to  get the font style of UILabel? Whether it is Bold or italic ?

Comment: Check here and you will get some idea [FontStyle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294179/select-bold-and-italicized-text-from-textfield)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to inspect the font name.

`myLabel.font.fontName`

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006891-CH4-SW16

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
NSAttributedString *string=yourLabel.attributedText;
if ([[textFieldFontName rangeOfString:string] length] > 0){
    NSLog(@"Bold");
}
if ([[textFieldFontName rangeOfString:string] length] > 0){
    NSLog(@"Italic");
}
```

**Note if your string contains both then, this may not work*

Answer (score -1):

Select your label in the interface builder (xib or storyboard) and go to the Attributes Inspector. There click on the "T" by font and then set font to Custom.
Now you can change the font, size etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
UILabel *myLabel;   
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"fontName" size:16.0];//set font according your choice
myLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];//bold font
myLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];//system font
```

Hope it's helpful for you....